# grunt jshint angular service Missing 'new' prefix when invoking a constructor

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, jshint, grunt-contrib-jshint

### gruntfile

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig({
        // This line makes your node configurations available for use
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        banner:
            '/*! <%= pkg.title || pkg.name %> - v<%= pkg.version %> - <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %>\n' +
            '<%= pkg.homepage ? " * " + pkg.homepage + "\\n" : "" %>' +
            ' * Copyright (c) <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy") %> <%= pkg.author %>;\n' +
            ' * Licensed <%= _.pluck(pkg.licenses, "type").join(", ") %>\n */\n',
        src: {
            js: ['src/**/*.js']
        },
        // This is where we configure JSHint
        jshint: {
           myFiles: ['gruntFile.js', '<%= src.js %>'],
           options:{
                newcap:true,
                globals:{}
           } 
        }
    });
    // Each plugin must be loaded following this pattern
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint']);

};
```

why when I run grunt I still have got

> Missing 'new' prefix when  invoking a constructor.
>           $scope.paginator =  Paginator(2,5,medias);

Paginator is a angular service/factory/provider

### UPDATE

it should be:

```
options:{
    newcap:false,
    globals:{}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about you jshint config object.  This is the pattern I use from npm with grunt-contrib-jshint https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-jshint

```
    jshint: {
        options: {
            jshintrc: 'jshintrc'
        },
        main: {
            src: [
                'app/js/**/*.js',
                'test/unit/**/*.js'
            ]
        }
    },
```

Maybe give that one a shot with the grunt-contrib-jshint package

Comment: I updated the question I set to true instead of false it happens :)